# Standard UCC SSL certificates for alias domains?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

This could be a stupid question, but I'm truly unsure what the right answer is. I have a client that wants multiple vanity/alias domains that redirect to the main domain. I already have SSL for the main domain, but I'm wondering if I need SSL for the other domains that redirect to the site. Normally I wouldn't worry so much about it, but this site will require credit card transactions and users to enter in personal information, so I want the site to be secure as possible.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can configure the multiple SSL alias domains, Need to generate the **CSR key** and upload the **crt and bundle** file on web-hosting.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is not if it can be done, but if it's necessary from a security standpoint.